# Simple measuring Ethernet throughput

Tags: stm32, ethernet, stm32cubemx

I have STM3220G-EVAL board (STM32F207IG MCU). I'd like to measure (approximately) its actual Ethernet throughput (board <-> Windows PC).

I have CubeMX sources. There are several examples (TCP, UDP, TFTP, web server). Which protocol, parameters and algorithm should I use? For example, passing file splitted into datagrams of certain size and so on.

Comment: You mean you wanna measure inside your microcontroller code ?

Comment: No, I can create or use existing utility for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "wireshark" software in your windows PC, to monitor incoming and outgoing Ethernet packets. It can also calculate the throughput of the data transfer. For more details:

https://www.google.co.in/amp/blog.davidvassallo.me/2010/03/22/measuring-bandwidth-using-wireshark/amp/